# "What's it going to take you to do..." vs. "what's it going to take for you to do..."

Tags: grammar, difference

Could you tell me if the word *for* adds anything to the meaning in the following context. It's from the sixth episode of the tenth season of *Friends*.

> Chandler: Look, I'm sorry I didn't give them your tape. And I promise,
> next time to submit you whether I think you are right for the part or
> not.
>
> Joey: That's not the point Chandler. The point is that you lied.
>
> Chandler: I know. You're right. **What's it gonna take for you to
> forgive** me.

How the meaning would change if Chandler dropped the *for*?

Comment: It takes x for [someone] to do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the type of situation where you can't omit ***'for' as a preposition*** when it is followed by an indirect object and to-infinitive. If you do so, your sentence will be meaningless.

Moreover, the structure *for + noun/pronoun [here, it is the subject of the to-infinitive clause] + to-infinitive* is very common in English, and in speech. It is therefore needed ,as I mentioned before, in order to complete the intended meaning of the aforementioned sentence.

***The sentence makes sense, and is correct as it is.***

I hope I provided a good explanation.

Comment: This is an idiom: what's it going to take [for some person to do y]

Comment: Probably. But It shouldn't be modified anyhow.